# Deploying wordpress to a server results in broken themes

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker

lets discuss the context of the situation quickly.

We have:

1. A docker container running a wordpress instance (Original wordpress docker image, however I have removed a "**VOLUME** line to persist data between images.").
2. A database running on a separate server (AWS RDS Aurora in this case.)
3. A docker running on a separate server (AWS ECS Fargate in this case).

How my deployment to production looks like (From a to z, everything is automated at least):

1. Create a **mysqldump** of a local wordpress database.
2. Run two **sed** commands against the dump file:

```
 - sed -i s|http:|https:|g dump.sql         //  To force https on newly added resources.

 - sed -i s|localhost|mydns.com|g dump.sql  //  Force using production dns name.
```

3. Deploy wordpress by pushing a new image created with **docker commit**.
4. Restore remote database with **mysql ... < dump.sql**

So where is the problem:

1. After the deployment site logos get reverted back to sample ones.
2. Custom CSS is showing some odd code that I did not write.
3. Some animations don't work.

What I know about the problem:

1. Web Browser console does not have any errors.
2. Network logs show that all requests succeed with http 200.

So, the questions:

1. Do you see any obvious disadvantages and possible pitfalls of a such deployment flow?
2. Is there a possibly better/more relaible deployment way?
3. Does anything come into your mind of what could possibly go wrong that results in broken themes?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have broken the database with the probability of 90%.Modern plugins and themes store links in db in serialized objects. Use proper tools to change links on db, let say wp-cli.

Comment: Humbly noted! Will get back to you to let you know if I have made any progress.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, you were right. These errors happen due the way wp_options are serialized. Changing DNS/IP breaks serialization.